# How to search for dates before 1970 with thinking sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have a search like so in my rails app:

```
Publication.search(terms, :with => {:publish_date => start_date..end_date})
```

However, if the start_date is before 1/1/1970, due to UNIX timestamps, the results will not show. I have records that have a publish_date before 1970 so I was just wondering what the best solution for this is, as I haven't been able to find one yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at storing them as integers by date, rather than timestamp: e.g. 1st January 1970 becomes 19700101.

This does mean you'd need to manually wrangle dates into the appropriate format within your index definitions though, and translate search requests accordingly too.

Comment: Is there any way to convert it without changing the database? Like i tried doing this:   `indexes publish_date.gsub("-", "").to_i, :as => :publish_date, :sortable => true` in the index file but I'm getting no enabled local indexes to search error. Tried a few different ways to do it through the index file but no luck yet.

Comment: If you're using SQL-backed indices (`:with => :active_record`) then you'll need to do that transformation in a SQL snippet: `has "CAST(publish_date as varchar)...", :as => :publish_date, :sortable => true`. Obviously the SQL in there needs work though - will leave that to you :)

Comment: Oh, but if you're using realtime indices, then you'll want a method in your model that returns the tweaked integer, then use that new method in your index definition instead: `has publish_date_as_int, :as => :publish_date, :type => :integer`

Comment: awesome! after some tinkering I settled on `has "CAST(DATE_FORMAT(publish_date, '%Y%m%d') AS SIGNED)", :as => :publish_date, :type => :integer, :sortable => true` I'm also converting them to integers in my model logic for search. Thanks so much for your help, took me a while to figure this out.

Comment: No worries. Also: you don't need `:sortable => true` - all attributes by their very nature are sortable. That option is only necessary for fields you want to sort by (and then it just creates a matching attribute for that field).